# Installing the SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) C library on the mac

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

How do you install the C library SDL on a mac. I would like to be able to use it with the IDE Code::Blocks. The compiler I am using is g++.

Comment: What have you tried? Did the instructions in the ReadMe not work? Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: There's nothing you can try. The mac version of SDL seems to come only with extension `.framework` which is used by Xcode. What if you don't want Xcode? Come on, there must be a way :(...